# Error Message After Forum Install

Tags: forum, discussion

Has anyone seen this error while going to browse their EE forum.  I just downloaded the latest EE Forum 3.1.19 and I am running EE 2.9.3.  The issue is this message.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Messages::can_send_pm() in /home/mysite/public_html/system/expressionengine/modules/forum/mod.forum.php on line 1215

Is this a known bug? How to work around it.

Comment: any other errors in apache?

Comment: looks pretty normal, nothing ee or forum related

Comment: Could try reinstalling to be sure

Comment: I did try that but no dice, same message.

Comment: Might be worth looming intriguing that line of code in your error. Are you running locally too? I only ask as you could try commenting out that can_send_pm function but wouldn't do that on a live site. That error sounds like your missing something EE is looking for. You could also reach out to Ellis lab for some ideas. Also try jumping on EE Slack chat and see if anyone else has ideas on the culprit.

Comment: I agree, something is odd, I removed that line of code and it went through to the forum but the ee code  {if pm_enabled} {/if} shows in the header. 

line commented 1215 of mod.forum.php

'pm_enabled'  => EE_Messages::can_send_pm(),

Comment: Hmm indeed! I'd email EL or ask on Slack

Comment: Yea, I am going to also start with a fresh install, install the discussion module and install 1 add-on at a time until the offender is found. Thanks for trying to help and the good suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan and best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had exactly the same issue.

The {if pm_enabled} {/if} conditional was only added in 2.10.0 which is causing the error.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-10-0

Upgrading EE to the latest fixes the issue.

Comment: great! glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Could be a themes files problems.
Did you put inside the EE themes folder the EE forum_themes folder??

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions to the nth.